# How to insert .png images to TClientDataSet .cds file?

Tags: delphi

I'm using Delphi XE8. Multi-device application.

Im my .cds file I've Field :[ID] Field type:ftAutoInc and Field :[IMAGE] Field type:ftGraphic.

I'd like insert only .png image to .cds file. But when I insert .png image into .cds it's inserting. when I try to load from .cds it gives message "Bitmap image is not valid".

So how to Solve this problem?

Thanks in Advance!

Here is my code:

```
procedure TForm1.btnImageInsertClick(Sender: TObject);
  var
  LStream : TMemoryStream;
begin
if OpenDialog1.Execute then
  begin

   Image1.Bitmap.LoadFromFile(OpenDialog1.FileName);

    LStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    Image1.Bitmap.SaveToStream(LStream);
   {
    cdsMenu2.Insert;
    cdsMenu2.FieldByName('IMAGE').Assign(Image1.Bitmap);
    cdsMenu2.Post;
   }

    cdsMenu2.Insert;
    TBlobField(cdsMenu2.FieldByName('IMAGE')).LoadFromStream(LStream);
    cdsMenu2.Post;
    cdsMenu2.SaveToFile(ExtractFileDir(ParamStr(0))+'\db\menu2.cds');

  end;
```

Comment: We readers can't see your screen.  Which **exact** line is it where the "Bitmap image is not valid" error occurs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this code it should works:

Add reference to unit Vcl.Imaging.pngimage;

```
procedure TForm1.btnImageInsertClick(Sender: TObject); 
var   
 LStream : TMemoryStream;   
 Png: TPngImage;  
begin 
 if OpenDialog1.Execute then  
  begin   
   Image1.Bitmap.LoadFromFile(OpenDialog1.FileName);   
   LStream:= TMemoryStream.Create;   
   Png:= TPngImage.Create;    
   try
    Png.Assign(Image1.Bitmap);
    Png.SaveToStream(LStream);
    LStream.Position:= 0;

    cdsMenu2.Insert;
    (cdsMenu2.FieldByName('IMAGE') as TBlobField).LoadFromStream(LStream);
    cdsMenu2.Post;
    cdsMenu2.SaveToFile(ExtractFileDir(ParamStr(0))+'\db\menu2.cds');   
   finally    
    LStream.Free;    
    Png.Free;   
   end;  
  end; 
end;
```